# The topbar's greatest injustice: Inconsistent font size

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar

Everyone has their own set of gripes about the redesigned top bar, but they're all neglecting the most egregious issue:

[image: top bars from different sites overlayed and compared side by side]

Look* at that inconsistent positioning**! The icons are shifted *whole pixels* because the computed font size for the top bar is inconsistent across the network. On some sites, such as Meta, the font size ends up being 13px, while on others like Gaming it's a meager 12px.

Admittedly I doubt most people would notice, but for users like me who have [multiple sites open in different tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4pz6.png) and switch between them, it's something you can't unsee after it's been seen. As it's easily fixed by just setting an explicit font size for `.topbar .network-items`, could that be done for the sake of Great Justice?

<sub>*The top section is the two examples overlayed

**There's also inconsistent colouring, but this is currently [by-designer](https://twitter.com/jzy/status/408696187105984512).</sub>

Comment: I've noticed something similar with the positioning of the reputation number on different sites

Comment: Ahhh! I hate you now!(+1)

Comment: Off topic, but you might be interested in something like [Veritabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/veritabs/nehjgjnfanppoiaikadimdkobpdahnmg) (I haven't used it, but [Tree Style Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/) for Firefox is amazing)

Comment: @Stijn Oh, cool. I have a (now apparently unavailable) Chrome extension that gives me a searchable list of open tabs, but my open tabs list in that particular window is pretty static so I typically navigate with muscle memory, heh.

Comment: I'm looking into this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You sir have the eyes of a Mongolian golden eagle. I have pushed a fix for this. Will go live after the next prod build.

Comment: This is high praise coming from the man who can see the difference between #FEFEFE and #FFFFFF

Comment: Why thank you for your promptness and compliment, I can only hope I am as majestic as one too.

Comment: Heh, that reminds me of the [hue test](http://www.xrite.com/custom_page.aspx?pageid=77&lang=en) @DavidFullerton.

Comment: @TimStone ironically, I scored higher on that than Jin did. His super eyes were no match for my studied patience. The test should really be timed.

Comment: @DavidFullerton what brand of fedora do you wear?